# How to disable JS? info windows from WP-FirePHP

Tags: debug

I'm using current ver of WP and WP-FirePHP.

When I load the WP dashboard, firebug's Console window shows the FirePHP data. That's all good.

As expected, the main browser window shows the WP Dashboard page itself.

**But,** the upper left corner of the browser window shows an iframe with textual debugging info. It appears to be the names of all of the WP scripts that were used to create the Dashboard page. And the upper right has another debugging iframe that tracks the mouse position.

**How do I get rid of, or move** those extra debugging iframes? 
And what exactly is being shown in them?
The upper left one hides needed parts of the page.

**ps** I don't have rep to create a FirePHP tag.

Answer (score 2):

[WP-FirePHP](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-firephp/) installs two debuggers:

1. FirePHP
2. [jQuery.debug](http://wellstyled.com/en/javascript-debug-jquery-plugin/)

This is only mentioned in passing on the WP-FirePHP plugin's page. Sigh.

To disable the jquery debugger, comment out a line in the WP-FirePHP plugin main file. See below. This can be done via the WP Plugin Edit command for the plugin.

```
function WPFirePHP() {
  add_action( 'admin_init', array(&$this, 'fb_exit') );
  # comment out the next line to remove the JQuery debugger
  ##### add_action( 'admin_init', array(&$this, 'add_scripts') );
}
```

Comment: Self-asked / self-answered, but still thanks for sharing.